# Do records showing the daily work of programmers exist?

Tags: training

Are there screencasts on the Internet showing screens of programmers that decided to record their daily work and show their programming style?

I'm interested in seeing how other programmers effectively use tools like an editor with various features, debugger, looking for bugs, profiler etc.

Maybe such "crazy programmers" exist that record everything they do and in the evening they realize that they did great mental job very efficiently and have the record, can additionally comment their intents which they still remember and share their effective hacks and coding style with other programmers.

Is there such a resource for learning (doesn't matter if free or payable)?

One particular portal or company which is focusing on this particular type of training and is leading in this area is sufficient for the answer.

Comment: Never thought of doing that, honestly.  There already exists a concept of [pair programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming) which is essentially what you're asking for, though that is usually done internally in a company and not for training purposes.

Comment: Very few companies are going to broadcast the source code of their IP (Intellectual Property). It will likely be developers on open-source projects. You can pull open-source code to read anyway, and programmers will likely focus on developing new features rather than take the time to display that. There are plenty of learning videos on e.g. Channel9, that's the closest you're going to get.

Comment: @Neil Yes, this is on a good way to watch what other is doing but when it would be recorded and selected only the useful parts, this could be successful in learning. I hope that somebody had this idea already.

Comment: @StuperUser I know about a lot of screencasts but focusing most in the stuff that can be learned from books.

Comment: Based on `"using effectively the tools like an editor with various features, debugger, looking for bugs, profiler etc."` There are videos on tooling and on debugging. A search for how to use eclipse debugger on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/results?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB416GB416&q=how+to+use+eclipse+debugger displays more than 1000 results.

Comment: My stab is that optimizing tool usage this way is the wrong approach. Sure, it's nice to be able to type and edit fast, but what's more important is the thought process that leads to a piece of code. I'd think plain old asking people how they work would yield you much deeper insights than merely watching what they type.

Comment: I am sure someone could convince Joel to do it with Fog Creek. Their self promotional video is very good on their website, I bet a day in the life of a programmer at Fog Creek would be amazing.

Comment: [Peepcode](https://peepcode.com/) has a few Ruby-centric "Play by play" screencasts that sound like possibly what you're after. Unless you're not interested in Ruby. Since you haven't given any detail about what tools or languages you want to familiarize yourself with, I'll assume you are. Why wouldn't you be? ;-)

Comment: Not sure what the question is but if the OP is talking about screen-casts that are used to demo some project or tool, these kinds of things are prepared in advance and practiced over-and-over for smoothness and speed.  In other words, they do not represent actual "working speed." Even the most elite and fast programmers (for example, Notch of minecraft) work at pace that is unwatchable in a normal screencast. The point of these recordings is to show how to do one particular thing in a clear way. The context and set-up is necessarily artificial.

Comment: @tdammers Thought process would be involved, but the emphasis would be rather on editing, refactoring or changing effectively code and on debugging, performance, optimizing and restructuring code. e.g. I'm debugging with my style and believe that I'm somewhere on the beginning of effective and fast work in searching for bugs.

Comment: @James Mostly imperative style like C, Python, Java. But language does not matter. I like most of the languages, only C++ is something unpleasant for me.

Comment: @Angelo Not a demo. It's something like a big brother on programmers with the exception that they are recording themselves and choose the best from their work. Things that brought them good feeling and excitemt during the day. Something that they've done with brilliance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are (commercial) sites that offer video training that do have "watch my screen" style videos:

- [TekPub](http://tekpub.com) by [Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/) (These ones specifically are $12.00 each, or subscription plans are avilable) - Has a ["Full Throttle"](http://tekpub.com/productions/ft_triage_oren) series where you watch a developer's screen while they work through real-world problems.  Not exactly "day-to-day" operations, but definitely a "true" experience.  Featuring:

  - Ayende Rahien
  - Brad Wilson
  - Rob Sullivan
- [PeepCode](https://peepcode.com) ([various plans available](https://peepcode.com/plans))  - Has a similar "Play by Play" series.  Featuring:

  - Jim Weirich
  - Aaron Patterson
  - Ryan Singer (UI)
  - Zed Shaw
  - Francis Hwang
  - John Barnette
  - Gary Bernhardt
- [WatchMeCode](http://www.watchmecode.net/) (Free to $12) - Not super familiar with this site, but it sounds like what you want given the name.  It does look like they have some "real-world" videos.

I've watched TekPub's video with Ayende and I think it's great.